# Syntax error in a ksh script: `2' is not expected

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to get the MD5 of some ears in a Unix box using the `fanout` command but there are some errors.

My code is:

```
ears=ear1-ear2
cluster=abc
dmgr=server1
k=$(expr `echo $ears | grep -o "-" | wc -l` + 1)

fanout "$dmgr" " umask 022 ; for k in $(seq 1 $k) ; do for i in $(echo $ears | cut -d'-' -f$k) ; do echo /appl/as/bin/md5 /appl/as/var/spool/ears/${cluster}/$i ; done ; done
```

The error I am getting is as follows :

```
ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 2 : `2' is not expected.
```

and it is unable to reference `$i`

Comment: It would be best if you detailed what you want to achieve and what results you expect from that command.

Comment: i want to get md5 from a box named server1

Comment: you've an extra `"` in your fanout command. please try after correcting it ?

Comment: There is no `2` on line 2. Also what you posted lacks a `#!` line. Post your actual, complete script if you want help. And fix your Shift key.

Comment: ` for k in $(seq 1 $k) ` not sure, this will do good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's failing with this error is the interpolation of `$(seq 1 $k)` inside your `fanout` command.

Let me explain...

Running `seq 1 2` returns this:

```
1
2
```

You have that inside double quotes, so the newline is kept as significant text. The fanout command therefore evaluates to this:

```
fanout server1  'umask 022 ; for k in 1
2 ; do for i in ear2 ; do echo /appl/as/bin/md5 /appl/as/var/spool/ears/abc/ ; done ; done'
```

Your `ksh` does not understand the `2` on the second line, so it bails.

You can fix this with the inclusion of `xargs`, but then you hit a second potential problem where you're using `k` as a loop counter, but the `$k` is evaluated before the loop runs. Furthermore, you have a subshell where `$ears` needs to be evaluated before the script runs but it's used within a loop that changes at runtime.

I've found a [man page](http://www.stearns.org/fanout/README.html) for `fanout` but I don't understand why you're running your loop against a single system (`server1`) when `fanout` exists to run a command against multiple systems. If you can explain the difference between a *server* and an *ear* I might be able to suggest a cleaner piece of code. My first suggestion might be this, though:

```
ears='ear1,ear2'
cluster=abc
dmgr=server1

fanout "$dmgr" "/appl/as/bin/md5 /appl/as/var/spool/ears/${cluster}/{$ears}"
```